# How to update my local branch with a merge?

Tags: git, merge

Being on my local branch feature/my_local_branche, I want to be updated with lastest commits done on a remote branch Release_X. Should i just stay on my local branch (feature/my_local_branche) and do :`git merge release_x` ?

I do not want to touch release_x, but to update only my local feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging changes requires their refs fetched locally. So you should fetch them first (`release_x`) and then merge changes into current branch (`my_local_branche`) via:

```sh
git fetch
git merge origin/release_x
```

Also you can you `pull` the `release_x`:

```sh
git pull origin release_x
```